# Kill a Java Thread without looping

Tags: java, timeout, kill

I'm using an external lib (Generex) in my project, and one constructor may take a very long time to execute, so I'd like to have a timeout (let's say 50 ms), and be able to know if the timeout has been reached or not.

So I was thinking at using a dedicated thread, and wrote the following code:

```
@Test
public void isComputable() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        System.out.println(check());

    Thread.sleep(300000);
}

private static boolean check() {

    final Thread stuffToDo = new Thread(() -> {while(true){}});

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Future future = executor.submit(stuffToDo);
    executor.shutdown();

    try {
        future.get(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException ie) {
        stuffToDo.interrupt();
        stuffToDo.stop();
        return false;
    }
    if (!executor.isTerminated())
        executor.shutdownNow();
    return true;
}
```

I replaced the call to the external lib with a while(true) loop, yet it is important to note that, in my case, I **cannot** use a loop to check if the thread was interrupted.

When executing this code, I've got well the answer after 50 ms for each call, yet the thread is not destroyed, and there is a high CPU usage, as we can see with JProfiler (note that the loop in the test over i is just to have a nicer chart):

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue please?

Note: I know that I should not use the deprecated stop method, I just tried everything I know to kill the thread.

Comment: The `stop` method is not just deprecated. It's dangerous to use (leaves resources in unpredictable states). Don't use it. Don't say "maybe I'll do it anyway". Treat `stop` as if it never existed. Anyway, you have to write your long method in a way that it can be interrupted. If not - you can't interrupt it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to this long method, it's in a dependency

Comment: You should check why the constructor takes a long time. Does it take long for everybody who uses it or just for your own use case? Does it always take long or does that depend on input? Do you have to construct a new object each time or perhaps constructing a single one or a pool of objects will work and so the time will not matter anymore?

Comment: it's a known issue of the lib: https://github.com/mifmif/Generex/issues/43
I want to avoid this issue by interrupting this constructor

Comment: Well, that approach won't really work. You can let it continue in the background and do other stuff in the meantime; Or you can research the regex you are using and try to find an alternative one that does not cause it to take a long time; Or you can get the source and add interruption capability yourself. The project seems to have been abandoned, otherwise I'd say consult with the author.

Comment: It's might be the case that if the range with which the regex generator is instantiated is large (in terms of number of strings it covers), it takes much more time. I mean, look at the constructor, it creates a DFA based on [this lib](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/automaton/). You could further dig into the source code, but probably it just depends on your regex. You could post it here, maybe somebody else can help. OR contact the Automaton lib devs.

Comment: Do you actually need to kill the construction process ? Wouldn't it be enough to continue processing (do any cleanup needed and ignore the constructed object) when timeout reached ?

Comment: @c0der if I don't kill the construction process, the CPU is getting very high for a long time, and since it's a cloud application, many threads can be impacted in the same way, leading to an unusable app.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to check for an interrupt regularly in your code callex or you have to run the code in another process. These are the only ways you can either interrupt or kill the process running the code.

I suggest taking a stack trace of the long running thread to help fix it in the future.